# How to turn JSONObject into JSONArray when JSON has wrong syntax?

Tags: java, arrays, json, api

I have the current response:

```
   "type":"champion",
   "format":"standAloneComplex",
   "version":"10.11.1",
   "data":{
      "Aatrox":{
         "version":"10.11.1",
         "id":"Aatrox",
         "key":"266",
         "name":"Aatrox",
         "title":"the Darkin Blade",
         "blurb":"Once honored defenders of Shurima against the Void, Aatrox and his brethren would eventually become an even greater threat to Runeterra, and were defeated only by cunning mortal sorcery. But after centuries of imprisonment, Aatrox was the first to find...",
         "info":{
            "attack":8,
            "defense":4,
            "magic":3,
            "difficulty":4
         },
         "image":{
            "full":"Aatrox.png",
            "sprite":"champion0.png",
            "group":"champion",
            "x":0,
            "y":0,
            "w":48,
            "h":48
         },
         "tags":[
            "Fighter",
            "Tank"
         ],
         "partype":"Blood Well",
         "stats":{
            "hp":580,
            "hpperlevel":90,
            "mp":0,
            "mpperlevel":0,
            "movespeed":345,
            "armor":38,
            "armorperlevel":3.25,
            "spellblock":32.1,
            "spellblockperlevel":1.25,
            "attackrange":175,
            "hpregen":3,
            "hpregenperlevel":1,
            "mpregen":0,
            "mpregenperlevel":0,
            "crit":0,
            "critperlevel":0,
            "attackdamage":60,
            "attackdamageperlevel":5,
            "attackspeedperlevel":2.5,
            "attackspeed":0.651
         }
      },
      "Ahri":{
         "version":"10.11.1",
         "id":"Ahri",
         "key":"103",
         "name":"Ahri",
         "title":"the Nine-Tailed Fox",
         "blurb":"Innately connected to the latent power of Runeterra, Ahri is a vastaya who can reshape magic into orbs of raw energy. She revels in toying with her prey by manipulating their emotions before devouring their life essence. Despite her predatory nature...",
         "info":{
            "attack":3,
            "defense":4,
            "magic":8,
            "difficulty":5
         },
         "image":{
            "full":"Ahri.png",
            "sprite":"champion0.png",
            "group":"champion",
            "x":48,
            "y":0,
            "w":48,
            "h":48
         },
         "tags":[
            "Mage",
            "Assassin"
         ],
         "partype":"Mana",
         "stats":{
            "hp":526,
            "hpperlevel":92,
            "mp":418,
            "mpperlevel":25,
            "movespeed":330,
            "armor":20.88,
            "armorperlevel":3.5,
            "spellblock":30,
            "spellblockperlevel":0.5,
            "attackrange":550,
            "hpregen":6.5,
            "hpregenperlevel":0.6,
            "mpregen":8,
            "mpregenperlevel":0.8,
            "crit":0,
            "critperlevel":0,
            "attackdamage":53.04,
            "attackdamageperlevel":3,
            "attackspeedperlevel":2,
            "attackspeed":0.668
         }
      }
}
}
```

(Last two curly brackets might be off as I hadto shorten the response as it is too large)
I am trying to create a JSONArray with every champion, so Aatrox first,Ahri second, etc..)

Due to the syntax of this response, using:

```
String returnString = (source);
JSONObject returnJSON = new JSONObject(returnString);
JSONArray arr= returnJSON.getJSONArray("data");
```

Does not seem to work, I think this is because of the lack of '[]' (square brackets) in the JSON. Is there a way I can still create a JSONArray with this current state?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Question looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/351454). Are you sure you want to *convert* the data to a `JSONArray`? Seems like what you actually want is simply to *iterate* the champions, i.e. iterate the fields of the `data` object, which is available as methods on the `JSONObject`. Since you didn't mention *which* JSON library you are using, I can tell you exactly how to do that, but why don't you have a **look at the documentation** of the `JSONObject` class in question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand that JSONObject is key,value pair and JSONArray is a list of any kind of objects. You can't just cast jsonObject to a JSONArray. 
IF you want to convert it You can do something like this..

```
    JSONArray output = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject dataObj = returnJSON.getJSONObject("data");
    Set<String> keys = dataObj.keySet();
    for (String key : keys) {
        JSONObject obj = dataObj.getJSONObject(key);
        // your logic for populating output
    }
```

Comment: That's not *converting* anything. It's just *iterating*.

Comment: Not getting ti what you exactly want to do with this line. JSONArray arr= returnJSON.getJSONArray("data");

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Needed to iterate through the JSONObject's keys. Set to answer, thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

Analyzing your JSON file with https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ it seems that you have missed the first curly braces. Adding them lead to a correct result.

```
{
   "type":"champion",
   "format":"standAloneComplex",
   "version":"10.11.1",
   "data":{
      "Aatrox":{
         "version":"10.11.1",
         "id":"Aatrox",
         "key":"266",
         "name":"Aatrox",
         "title":"the Darkin Blade",
         "blurb":"Once honored defenders of Shurima against the Void, Aatrox and his brethren would eventually become an even greater threat to Runeterra, and were defeated only by cunning mortal sorcery. But after centuries of imprisonment, Aatrox was the first to find...",
         "info":{
            "attack":8,
            "defense":4,
            "magic":3,
            "difficulty":4
         },
         "image":{
            "full":"Aatrox.png",
            "sprite":"champion0.png",
            "group":"champion",
            "x":0,
            "y":0,
            "w":48,
            "h":48
         },
         "tags":[
            "Fighter",
            "Tank"
         ],
         "partype":"Blood Well",
         "stats":{
            "hp":580,
            "hpperlevel":90,
            "mp":0,
            "mpperlevel":0,
            "movespeed":345,
            "armor":38,
            "armorperlevel":3.25,
            "spellblock":32.1,
            "spellblockperlevel":1.25,
            "attackrange":175,
            "hpregen":3,
            "hpregenperlevel":1,
            "mpregen":0,
            "mpregenperlevel":0,
            "crit":0,
            "critperlevel":0,
            "attackdamage":60,
            "attackdamageperlevel":5,
            "attackspeedperlevel":2.5,
            "attackspeed":0.651
         }
      },
      "Ahri":{
         "version":"10.11.1",
         "id":"Ahri",
         "key":"103",
         "name":"Ahri",
         "title":"the Nine-Tailed Fox",
         "blurb":"Innately connected to the latent power of Runeterra, Ahri is a vastaya who can reshape magic into orbs of raw energy. She revels in toying with her prey by manipulating their emotions before devouring their life essence. Despite her predatory nature...",
         "info":{
            "attack":3,
            "defense":4,
            "magic":8,
            "difficulty":5
         },
         "image":{
            "full":"Ahri.png",
            "sprite":"champion0.png",
            "group":"champion",
            "x":48,
            "y":0,
            "w":48,
            "h":48
         },
         "tags":[
            "Mage",
            "Assassin"
         ],
         "partype":"Mana",
         "stats":{
            "hp":526,
            "hpperlevel":92,
            "mp":418,
            "mpperlevel":25,
            "movespeed":330,
            "armor":20.88,
            "armorperlevel":3.5,
            "spellblock":30,
            "spellblockperlevel":0.5,
            "attackrange":550,
            "hpregen":6.5,
            "hpregenperlevel":0.6,
            "mpregen":8,
            "mpregenperlevel":0.8,
            "crit":0,
            "critperlevel":0,
            "attackdamage":53.04,
            "attackdamageperlevel":3,
            "attackspeedperlevel":2,
            "attackspeed":0.668
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Not an answer, since it doesn't answer the question.